# How to save files in temp directory for any platform?

Tags: grails, temp

I have a Grails application in which I generate PDF/Excel files in a folder.

My problem is, everytime I need to change the directory path through code when I test or run the code on different machines like Windows, Linux, Mac.

So what is the generic path, which will be applicable for *any/all* platforms as the default temp directory, so that I won't need to manually set path for the directory while running code on different machines/platforms.

Comment: Thanks for editing, will reply you after checking your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The temp directory is available via

```
String tempDir = System.getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')
```

Answer (score 3):

To create temp files in the default location for the OS you can use [`File.createTempFile(prefix,suffix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Also available via java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-